# BindingResult alternative in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I am shifting from Spring Boot.I have a couple of questions:
Is there any alternative to BindingResult in Quarkus?
my method is like this:

```
@PUT
public Response updateCategory(@Valid CategoryDTO pCategoryDTO) {}
```

And the request is this:

```
{  "name": "packaging",  "id": 8}
```

But pCategoryDTO doesn't receive id(Integer), it only gets the name.I don't see any errors in logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the Hibernate Validator Quarkus extension added?

Also is `CategoryDTO` in a place that is properly indexed by Jandex? (i.e. either in your app, or if it's in an external library, it needs to be indexed)

If so, you should have an exception raised if the bean is not valid.